# Running an Angular2 app via index.html

Tags: angularjs, angular, production-environment

I have built an Angular 2 app using TS and SystemJS and am running it via the standard "npm start" as shown in the "Tour of Heroes" example on the website. But now I want to upload it for production. So how do I go about converting the application so I can open it via a simple double clicking of the index.html (as in Angular 1.5)?

Comment: you need to provide a lot more information for anyone to give you an answer on this... Did you start with a seed project? Are you using webpack? SystemJS? Gulp?

Comment: Yeah I started with the seed in the Angular 2 website using SystemJS.

Comment: you cant. the back end serve the index.html after handling routes, you need to run your application from the command line unless you are using some sort of GUI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to create simple build is to use angular-cli. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

One line to build app for production:

```
ng build --prod
```

So, if you like it, I would suggest you to do following steps:

1)Create simple angular-cli application and make a test deploy

2)Update angular from rc4 to rc5 (angular-cli uses rc4, but angular tutorial uses rc5). This page will help you https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html (if you read this post from future, this step must be outdated)

3)Copy modules you've already developed to this angular-cli application.

Answer (score 1):

Run this

```
ng build --prod --bh .
```

This will allow you to double click the `index.html` file.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. I have tried this with my application but routing was not working for it. Seems it broke somewhere due to angular restrictions. You can able to open static index HTML file only.